# Verify password hash using password_verify and MySQL

Tags: php

I'm trying to store an encrypted password in MySQL and as for the register part it works as it should how ever when i try to do the login things go south.

I can not verify $_POST['password'] against the hash stored in MySQL.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my register.php which works as it should:

**register.php (working)**

```
$post_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$password_hash = password_hash($post_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
mysqli_query goes here...
```

**login.php (not working)**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("XXX","XXX","XXX","XXX");
$post_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$post_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

// Getting the stored Hash Password from MySQL
$getHash = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM anvandare WHERE username = '$post_username'"));
$got_Hash = $getHash['password'];

// Checking if what the user typed in matches the Hash stored in MySQL
// **This is where it all goes wrong**
if (password_verify($post_password, $got_Hash)) {
echo "The posted password matches the hashed one";
}
else {
echo "The posted password does not match the hashed one";
}
```

When I run the code above I get the "Correct password" message **by just entering the username** and leaving the password field out.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your are not converting the newly entered password at the time of login into hash for comparing, like you did when storing them,

Comment: did you try mysqli_fetch_array?? plus do convert your password by password_hash()

Comment: @DennisEnström it happend to every one.

Comment: @habibulhaq is right it happens to everyone. will write it as a answer.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is for making a string safe for inserting into a database. It is not for making a string safe for running through a hashing function.

Comment: @habib et al: He's using the `password_hash` API correctly! No problems here.

Comment: @Dennis Do some basic debugging and check that your hashed password is making a roundtrip through your database intact. A very common problem is that the database field is too short and is truncating the hash. Also, as Quentin said, **don't escape the password before hashing it**. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for a bigger picture view of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need to make sure that you are allowing more than 100 characters in your password column so that all the hashed password can be saved in the field. This was also happening with me, the script was correct and everything was working fine but the only mistake I was doing was that I didn't allow more than 40 characters in the password field which was the biggest error. After incrementing the maximum limit from 40 to 100, everything is working fine:)